# Building nested lists from ancestor data?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

Given the structure:

```
{
    id: 'id-1',
    name: 'name1',
    ancestors: []
},{
    id: 'id-2',
    name: 'name2',
    ancestors: []
},{
    id: 'id-3',
    name: 'name3',
    ancestors: ['id-1']
},{
    id: 'id-4',
    name: 'name4',
    ancestors: ['id-3', 'id-1']
}
```

- Assume they are not sorted in any meaningful way.
- The ancestors field is an array showing the path up to top level.

What would be the most efficient way to build nested lists (ul)?

My first thought is a recursive approach, but that seems troublesome as it would repeatedly search the entire list.  Since this will be a javascript solution running in the browser that could be problematic.

Comment: What about building the tree backend side?

Comment: How can one element have multiple ancestors?

Comment: @Cid nodejs?!?!

Comment: @JonasW. whatever the language, if it's a client-server application, he could build the tree server-side

Comment: Are we to assume that the strings in `ancestors` arrays will be ids of existent objects? Could there, for example, be a string id whose object doesn't exist? Also how to read the `ancestors` array? Can you post the expected output of the example provided in the question?

Comment: @JonasW. There is only one parent, but once the tree becomes more than two levels deep there are many "ancestors".  As id-1 is the parent of id-3 and id-3 is the parent of id-4.  So id-4 has two ancestors.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir We can assume the ids will exist.

Comment: @fyubo ah okay, so you actually just need the first ancestor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a tree and then render a nested list.

```js
function getTree(data) {
    var o = {};
    data.forEach(function (a) {
        var parent = a.ancestors[0];
        if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].children) {
            a.children = o[a.id].children;
        }
        o[a.id] = a;
        o[parent] = o[parent] || {};
        o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
        o[parent].children.push(a);
    });
    return o.undefined.children;
}

function buildList(tree, target) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    tree.forEach(o => {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.name));
        buildList(o.children || [], li);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    target.appendChild(ul);
}

var data = [{ id: 'id-1', name: 'name1', ancestors: [] }, { id: 'id-2', name: 'name2', ancestors: [] }, { id: 'id-3', name: 'name3', ancestors: ['id-1'] }, { id: 'id-4', name: 'name4', ancestors: ['id-3', 'id-1'] }],
    tree = getTree(data);

console.log(tree);
buildList(tree, document.body);
```

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, this will require only one loop through the objects, but will require a lot of space as each item will exist in o multiple times.  So it has very low computational complexity, but high space complexity?

Comment: no, one item exists only once. the reference is store often. if you have a look to `o`, then you get all parents and nodes inside with nested children, which are references to a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Build up a Map for faster lookup:

```
 const byId = new Map(array.map(el => ([el.id, el]));
```

Then its pretty simple to create a nested tree, we just check if a node has no ancestors, then its a root element, otherwise we add it as a children of the parent:

```
 const root = [];

 for(const obj of array) {
   if(obj.ancestors.length) {
     const parent = byId.get(obj.ancestors[0]);
     if(parent.children) {
       parent.children.push(obj);
     } else {
       parent.children = [obj];
     }
   } else {
    root.push(obj);
   }
 }
```

So now `root` contains a nested tree, you can use a recursive approach to traverse it:

```
 function traverse(elements) {
    for(const el of elements) {
      // Render ...
      traverse(el.children || []);
    }
 }

 traverse(root);
```